# Importing Simple Transformer

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

Facing this error when I am trying to import `simpletransformers`.

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel, ClassificationArgs
```

Error:

```
 cannot import name 'Unigram' from 'tokenizers.models' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tokenizers/models/__init__.py)
```

Comment: My guess is that you have an old version of the `tokenizers` package, try updating it.

Comment: Yeap, it works! Thanks